# Calling second GET request for separate view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to call the GET method in my show_page view when the GET method in the main_page view is called. With the code I am using now, I know the show_page GET method is being called because I tested it with a print statement. However, it is not creating the actual GET request so that the page refreshes. Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
class show_page(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    template = 'wait/show.html'

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, request):
        username = request.user.username
        customers = Customer.objects.filter(store_username=username).exclude(exited=True)
        return render(request, cls.template, {'customers' : customers})


class main_page(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    template = 'wait/main.html'

    def get(self, request):
        username = request.user.username
        customers = Customer.objects.filter(store_username=username).exclude(exited=True)

        refresh = show_page.get(request)

        return render(request, self.template, {'customers' : customers})
```

Comment: You're saving the response from `show_page.get(request)` as variable `refresh` and then returning a new response. So what is your plan?

Comment: I guess you should do something with `refresh` returned by `show_page.get`.

Comment: Would it be better to not save it as a variable? The variable serves no purpose. I'm just not sure why it's calling the method but not refreshing the page.

Comment: I am trying to get it to return the response of both main_page and show_page.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever, you can't return two responses. A django view handles **one HTTP request** and returns **one HTTP response**. That's the purpose of each view. Which template do you need to render? If you have common functionality in two different views, just move that to a separate function (regular python function) and use that function in both views.

Comment: @dirkgroten how would I move the functionality of the get methods to a regular python function?

Comment: define a function and call it. Just like any python function.

Comment: But it’s not clear anyway what you’re trying to achieve. Both views show and main do the same except using a different template. What do you want to return to the user?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to call the show GET request when the main has a GET request so that the show updates without refreshing it first.